# Select the row conditioning on the first occurence of a fixed value using R

Tags: r, select

Here is my repeated measurements dataframe

```
subject  StartTime_month  StopTime_month  ...

1          0.0            0.5
1          0.5            1.0  
1          1.0            3.0
1          3.0            6.0
1          6.0            9.6
1          9.6            12.1
2          0.0            0.5
2          0.5            1.0 
2          1.0            1.9
2          1.9            3.2
2          3.2            6.2
2          6.2            8.2
```

I would like to select the rows which have the first StopTime_month >6.0 for each subject

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'subject', get the row index of the first instance where 'StopTime_month' is greater than 6, and use that to subset the rows

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df1[,  .I[which(StopTime_month > 6)[1]], by = subject]$V1]
#   subject StartTime_month StopTime_month
#1:       1             6.0            9.6
#2:       2             3.2            6.2
```

Supppose, if we need all the rows until the first instance of 'StopTime_month' greater than 6,

```
setDT(df1)[, .SD[cumsum(StopTime_month > 6)<2], by = subject]
#     subject StartTime_month StopTime_month
# 1:       1             0.0            0.5
# 2:       1             0.5            1.0
# 3:       1             1.0            3.0
# 4:       1             3.0            6.0
# 5:       1             6.0            9.6
# 6:       2             0.0            0.5
# 7:       2             0.5            1.0
# 8:       2             1.0            1.9
# 9:       2             1.9            3.2
#10:       2             3.2            6.2
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   filter(StopTime_month > 6) %>%
   group_by(subject) %>% 
   slice(1L)
#   subject StartTime_month StopTime_month
#     <int>           <dbl>          <dbl>
#1       1             6.0            9.6
#2       2             3.2            6.2
```

Comment: I never uses data.table package during my research life. But its power has been shown up quite often. I need to get familiar with this package. Nice job!

Comment: @AmyJuanLi  Yes, it is very powerful.  It becomes more obvious when you do data analysis on big datasets.

Answer (score 1):

With `base R` `aggregate`

```
aggregate(.~subject, df[df$StopTime_month > 6, ], function(x) x[1])

#  subject StartTime_month StopTime_month
#1       1             6.0            9.6
#2       2             3.2            6.2
```

Answer (score 0):

A `base R` solution:

*For subject 1:*

```
df[df$subject==1 & df$StopTime_month > 6,][1,]
```

*For subject 2:*

```
df[df$subject==2 & df$StopTime_month > 6,][1,]
```

(where `df` is your dataframe)

Comment: It makes sense for only a few subjects, but I have thousands of subjects in my case.

Comment: wrap it in a function and use `apply`.